# WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want when this happens to ask for new variables using declare, but when I run it asks me everything in the begining:

```
Set serveroutput on;

DECLARE 
      v_aid ALUNO.AID%TYPE := &vs_aid;
      v_aluno ALUNO%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN 

     SELECT *
     INTO v_aluno
     FROM ALUNO
     WHERE aid = v_aid;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('-------------------------'); 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Já existe um ID com os seguintes dados:'); 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Nome: '||v_aluno.nome||' | Data Nascimento: '|| v_aluno.data_nascimento); 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('-------------------------'); 
      EXCEPTION 
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        DECLARE 
        aid int := v_aid;
        nome varchar(30) := '&sv_nome';
        data_nascimento date := '&sv_data';

      INSERT INTO Aluno 
           (     aid 
                , nome 
                , data_nascimento 
                ) 
      VALUES  
           ( aid 
                , nome 
                , data_nascimento 
                ) ;



 END;
```

Sorry if my code isnt well made, I'm not expert in SQL just trying to solve a problem.

Edit: I'm using oracle PL/SQL

Comment: Could you edit and clarify what SQL Server you are using? The syntax may be a bit different.

Comment: Done. Its Oracle PL/SQL

Comment: you cannot do that. The user input variables are asked before everything, and the script is pre-compiled with it. You should create a stored procedure instead, accepting the name of students as input

Comment: Is there any way to make what I want then?

Comment: I've found a workaround. Thanks everyone! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a stored procedure instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_STUDENT(I_STUDENTID IN NUMBER, I_STUDENTNAME AS VARCHAR2, I_BIRTHDATE AS DATE) IS
    v_aluno ALUNO%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 

    SELECT * INTO v_aluno FROM ALUNO WHERE aid = I_STUDENTID;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('-------------------------'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Já existe um ID com os seguintes dados:'); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Nome: '||v_aluno.nome||' | Data Nascimento: '|| v_aluno.data_nascimento); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('-------------------------'); 

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        INSERT INTO Aluno 
           (     aid 
                , nome 
                , data_nascimento 
                ) 
        VALUES  
           ( I_STUDENTID 
                , I_STUDENTNAME 
                , I_BIRTHDATE 
                ) ;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
END ADD_STUDENT;
```

And call it this way:

```
DECLARE
    sName       Aluno.nome%TYPE;
    iId         Aluno.aid%TYPE;
    dtBirthDate Aluno.data_nascimento%TYPE;
BEGIN
    ADD_STUDENT(iId, sName, dtBirthDate);
END;
```